# Problems with the secret key and github (gpg)

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I would like to verify my GitHub commits. Unfortunately I can't connect the gpg key with git. Can you help me?

I took the instructions from the GitHub Docs as a basis.

- https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/generating-a-new-gpg-key

I've created a key with the following commands:

```bash
gpg --full-generate-key
```

Subsequently, I exported it so that I could use it, in this case, with GitHub:

```bash
gpg --armor --export <Key-ID>
```

I reset the Git GPG configuration:

```bash
git config --global --unset gpg.format
```

Then, I set my key as the default key:

```bash
git config --global user.signingkey <KEY-ID>
```

and configured signing as the default:

```bash
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

The issue I'm facing is as follows: when I try to sign commits, the following problem occurs:

```bash
git commit -S -m "gpg Test"
gpg: skipped <KEY-ID>: No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Do you have any ideas?

All packages (including git and gpg) are up-to-date. I have done this in Windows and Ubuntu. I get the same error everywhere. So it seems like I have a fundamental problem.

.gitconfig:

```bash
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
[user]
    name = eskopp
    email = email :)
    user = eskopp
    signingkey = <KEY-ID>
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

I was hoping that I could use the `git commit -S -m "gpg test"` conmmit to verify my commits.